# My python exe (cx_freeze) doesn't work after push and pull from git

Tags: python, wpf, cx-freeze, pythonpath

Problem is with running my code. In the project, WPF (C#) application should run executable python file made with cx_freeze. Problem is that it WORKS ONLY when I pass the project as a .zip to another people. When I'm trying to push to git and then pull somewhere this code cmd throws error as you can see below. I saw threads with same error and other said that PYTHONHOME nad PYTHONPATH should be unset. But as you can see they're unset (and default were). Project contains WPF application that runs python .exe code in background after logging in. Folder with built code contains main.exe file that is runned in WPF, folders with python packages (.py files), folder lib with files you can see on the screen and files - python3.dll, python38.dll. I want to make it work not only from .zip package, but either after pulling it from git repository.

[folders added with cx_freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmvxC.png)

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\d4wt0\Desktop\pracka\wpf1207\desktopapp2\experiment_stream\build\exe.win-amd64-3.8\main.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 1
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\Desktop\\pracka\\wpf1207\\desktopapp2\\experiment_stream\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.8\\main.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\Desktop\\pracka\\wpf1207\\desktopapp2\\experiment_stream\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.8\\main.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\Desktop\\pracka\\wpf1207\\desktopapp2\\experiment_stream\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.8\\lib\\library.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\d4wt0\\Desktop\\pracka\\wpf1207\\desktopapp2\\experiment_stream\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.8\\lib',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003040 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

running exe from c#:

```
static readonly string path_prefix = "\\..\\..\\..\\..";
static string dir_path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

private static void run_file(string fileName, bool wait = false)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            info.Arguments = "/K " + fileName;
            Process.Start(info);
        }

public static void select_ROI()
        {
            if (run_py)
            {
                string select_roi = dir_path + path_prefix + "\\experiment_stream\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.8\\main.exe";
                run_file(select_roi);
            }
        }
```

setup.py to build exe with cx_freeze:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = ['calibration_package/points.csv', 'ffmpeg/', 'calibration_package/',
                'communication_package/', 'gaze_tracker_package/', 'model_package/', 'recorder_package/',
                'log_package/', 'CASES/', 'configs/'
                ]

packages = ['os', 'socket', 'cv2', 'pathlib', 'glob', 'time', 'numpy', 'pandas',
            'subprocess', 'signal', 'sklearn', 'json', 'scipy', 'random',
            'imutils.video', 'PIL', 'threading', 'queue', 'configparser'
            ]

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "ET",
    version = "0.2",
    description = "eye_tracker",
    options = {"build_exe": {'packages': packages, 'include_files': includefiles}},
    executables = [Executable("main.py")]
)
```